# limit point of $\frac{1}{m}\sin(m)$ for $m \geq1$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How do I show that 0 is the only limit point of $\frac{1}{m}\sin(m)$ for $m \geq1$ integer? It is clear that 0 is a limit point since it is the limit of this sequence, but I cannot prove that there are no other limit points, although I can easily see that it does not happen.

Comment: If a sequence has a limit, then it has exactly only limit point (which is, unsurprisingly, the limit). In general, if a sequence lies in $[a,b]$ then all the limit points much also be in $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

you can show a convergent sequence can have exactly one limit point. (Suppose not, you have a subsequence convergent to it, then it will contradict to the convergence of the sequence).

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
0\leq\left|\frac{\sin m}{m}\right|=\frac{|\sin m|}{m}\leq\frac{1}{m}.
$$
You can then employ the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) to infer that $(\sin m)/m\to 0$. The limit point is unique because for large $m$, $(\sin m)/m$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence has a limit, then it has exactly only limit point.

**Proof:** Suppose that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=A$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=B$. Then for any $\epsilon >0$, then there exists $N_1$ when $n> N_1$, $|A-a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and there exists $N_2$ when $n> N_2$, $|B-a_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Now when $n > \max\{N_1, N_2\}$, $$|A-B|=|A-a_n+a_n-B|\le |A-a_n|+|B-a_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} =\epsilon ,$$

whcih shows that $A=B$.